# Getting all PIDs from ls /proc

Tags: bash, unix

How could I separate all PIDs using ls /proc so that I would be able to make a list of these PIDs? I am going to create a script, in which I need to advert to each PID.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `cd /proc; pids=([0-9]*)` will get all pids into `pids` array.  It is not a good practice to parse `ls` output.  See: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Or `pids=( /proc/[0-9]*/ ); pids=( ${pids[@]//[^[:digit:]]/} )` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
cd /proc
pids=( +([0-9]) )
cd -
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
    do_something_with "$pid"
done
```